# Types of conflicts in Bison

Tags: bison, yacc

```
%token<val>num 
%left '+' '-'
```

Example for `shift/reduce` conflict:

```
Expr:num {$$=$1};
     |Expr '+' Expr;{};
     |Expr '-' Expr;{};
```

I want to recognize the `reduce/reduce` conflict.
It occurs when two or more rules apply to same sequence of input (token)

For example:

```
Prod: proda|prodb
     proda :'x'
     prodb : 'x'
```

Could anyone to give some ideas how to recognise `reduce/reduce` conflict easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to create y.output file.

Use command `yacc -v parser_name.y`. This will create you output how yacc works. Find state where yacc says your conflict is, and then it is very important to understand what point sign . in file means.

If your output file says something like this:

> 4  |Expr. '+' Expr;{};

Point sign after expression is saying to you: "I've read Expr and on input I have '+'.

Reduce-Reduce conflicts appear when you have situation like this:

```
NON_TERMINAL1: Expr.
NON_TERMINAL2: Expr.
```

In this situation, where you have Expr. at the end of the rule Yacc doesn't know which reduce to do and that is Reduce-Reduce conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've just pretty much described the difference between the conflicts. What's the question?

`shift/reduce` conflict means that bison doesn't know if he should `shift` (read one more terminal and place it on the top of its stack) or `reduce` (convert several terminals/non-terminals on the stack into a new non-terminal). `shift/reduce` means `I don't know - should I apply a rule now or wait a bit, read some text and apply another rule there?` Such conflicts are usually resolved with `shift` operation.

`reduce/reduce` conflict means that there are two or more ways to reduce terminals/non-terminals on the top of the stack. `reduce/reduce` means `I don't know - should I apply this rule or that rule now?`. This conflict is much more serious than `shift/reduce` - the grammar is ambiguous and something is really wrong.

Usually it's better not to *recognize* reduce/reduce, but *avoid* it. Have a clear idea of what you want to do from the start. Revise your grammar from time to time. Is there a chance you've just reinvented another rule?

When it comes to debugging existing conflicts, `bison -v` option creates an `*.output` file with a very long descriptions of all your conflicts. It's pretty hard to read for the first time and it requires some knowledge about how `LR1 parsing` is conducted, but the pros of reading it are great too.